# QLayout and discrete widget representation - how to?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qwidget

Lets, for example, we have QHBoxLayout inside QMainWindow.

Lets we have set of the widgets inside above layout.

But (**!**) few of widgets have discrete visual representations.
In another words they have few states dependent on available space.

For example:

1. if there are too much available space - it must look like big image + some text
2. if there available minimal space - it must look like little image
3. if there available few more than minimal space - it must look like button + label
4. etc...

So when the user change the main window size our "dynamic" widgets must show own representation dependent on available space.

How it could be achieved in Qt?

UPD: the closest behavior present in the Microsoft ribbon interface

UPD2: the QML closest behavior present in gif below (on part where window resized by user)

[image]

UPD3: more complex example - each panel in the menu panel change content elements view and count that depends from available space 
[image]

Comment: There's `sizeHint` .. would that work for you?

Comment: From what you've described it sounds as if each `QWidget` within the `QHBoxLayout` should override [`QWidget::resizeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) and adjust its contents/appearance according to its new size.

Comment: @"Jesper Juhl" I looked at it but didnt find any way how to retrieve new requested size. This function dont helps me :(

Comment: @G.M. I tried, but when I descrease the window size the resizeEvent stops fired when all widgets completely fit all window space. So I cant compare that requested size is less than my complex widget size -> so I cant change the widget view

Comment: similar with this https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/tree/master/ResponsiveLayout?

Comment: @Jui yes its looks like that I need. Can it be achieved without QML? (just using usual layouts)

Comment: @AeroSun: You would have more chance to get a nice answer by making your question more specific. Can't you at least provide the code of the widget you'll have in your layout (to illustrate what you really mean by "discrete visual representations" and ""dynamic widgets") and drawingw of what you expect the layout to do?

Comment: Hopefully this will do: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html

Comment: @jpo38 I dont know how to describe what I want more clear. In UPD2 part I add the movie with closes behavior implemented in QML - I need it without QML.

Comment: @AlexanderV I followed your link and there all logic working over "sizeHint" of concrete widget. It is trouble for me - for returning desired size I need to know the available space. So I didnt find any way how to apply it to my case.

Comment: Say you have `n` buttons like this in a layout. Each of them are scaling dynamically as the window resizes. That means the control logic for collapsing and expanding the button needs to be in the layout, not the button. So yes, you need to write your own layout class.

Comment: @Jon Harper, it is not exactly. Say I have n buttons in a layout with size S. When the layout resized to size < S few buttons must be replaced by label with less size than button have. If layout resized again to size << S - some of the control must hide. Look at the UPD3 - there are more complex example. Each panel change elements count and view dependent on the available state

Comment: @Jon Harper and second point - I dont think that your suggested approach are good, because in that case the layout must have code for each widget type. Finelly the layout object will transform to huge GOD-object that is development anti-pattern

Comment: My approach is that taken by QT's layout engine. The layouts feed data to the widgets when they are to resize.

Comment: @Jon Harper, maybe I didnt get your point correctly. Could you show how it must be implemented by example?

Comment: @AeroSun I recommend a stroll through the Qt source tree to get a feel for how their layout engine and layout classes work. It'll put everything in context.

Comment: @JonHarper `QLayout`s do not change the contents of the contained widgets. They may resize or move them around, but not, say, hide elements within the widgets which no longer fit. It's up to the widget to do that. For example a button or label may have an Elide Mode setting which determines what happens when the text doesn't fit. The Layout doesn't/shouldn't know anything about it. I agree the first example ("Responsive Layout") does make sense as a custom Layout, because it is not actually modifying anything within the contained widgets. The MS toolbar example is completely different though.

Comment: @MaxPaperno Officially, you are correct. Behind the scenes, Qt's layout engine gets up to all kinds of chicanery. I did not mean to imply that the layout implementation here would do so, however.

Comment: @JonHarper Chicanery like changing *contents* of the contained widgets? Can you give an example? I've just never observed this myself (and would probably consider it a bug?). Geometry, sure, but even that can be completely controlled with widget size policies, layout cell stretch factors, alignments, and custom sizeHint() when needed.

Comment: @MaxPaperno Poking my head around QLayout and the related source, it looks like they've *really* cleaned up that sort of behavior in the layout engine and layout classes since 5.0. I couldn't find a non-`const`-preserving example except for explicitly setting the geometry. There's still lots of reaching through the d-ptr to *read* data, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, I will use Qt-equivalent terms, not the official MS Ribbon terminology.

#### An Overview

You are actually looking at a number of layouts, in a pattern like so:

```
QToolbar
| (Layout)
+--> QGroupBox/QToolButton
|     | (Layout)
|     +----->Button
|     +----->Button
+--> QGroupBox/QToolButton
```

#### The Pattern

Let's start with *just* the `QGroupBox` that populates helps sort our buttons into groups.

Consider that our group box may hold *both* our dynamic `QToolButton` and regular widgets. When the available space *shrinks*, the layout:

- Calculates the minimum space required for fixed-sized widgets and the `minimumSizeHint()` values of the widgets without fixed size policies.
- Apportions the remaining space based on the growth policy of each widget.
- *However*, our dynamic tool button *may or may not* change size depending on available space.
- Now we have to start checking if the children of the layout are dynamic or not, using `qobject_cast`.
- When we find a dynamic button, we have to determine if it can shrink or not. If it does, we cache this and its preferred, smaller size.
- If it's going to shrink, we have to recalculate our minimum size.
- And then we have to keep going, hoping that shrinking the buttons during resize doesn't cause any tricky tie-breakers.
- Tie breakers: if two buttons can collapse to a smaller size, which one goess first? We have to account for *that*, too. Also, MS uses rows of three buttons. We can't collapse one from `Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon` to `Qt::ToolButtonIconOnly`, we have to collapse a set of three.
- Three horizontal buttons can collapse to three vertical buttons. This, too, needs to be calculated and cached.

#### There is hope.

We can simplify by making each container *only* able to hold dynamic tool buttons. Then we don't have to deal with tricky issues like fixed sized widgets and we only need to deal with one type of widget.

Microsoft has also helpfully implemented this behavior for us. You can learn a lot about the behavioral constraints of your layout and child widgets by empirical observation. When do groups collapse? If a group collapses, do other groups expand to take up the space? (The answer to that is no, by the way.) How do buttons group together as they collapse? Are some special in how they collapse and expand (constraints on their expansion and collapsing behavior)?

Qt has also implemented several layouts for us to study and get an idea of how they work and how they are different. `QGridLayout` is a promising basis, particularly if you do some math to change the row span of widgets on the fly (this is for grouping buttons as they collapse from vertical layout to sets of three horizontal buttons).

#### In Summary

Completely answering your question is far too broad to be on-topic on SO, but I hope this info guides you where you need to go.

Comment: Good step-by-step breakdown of resizing issues, indeed it's not a trivial affair. But this is stuff the existing QLayouts already do. A "dynamic" object in this example is pretty much anything w/out a QSizePolicy::Fixed and inside a layout cell which can change size (no constraints). That's a basic function of layouts. I do also agree with your summary, and in fact we don't even know if a toolbar is really what the OP is using this for...  :)  Also was wondering what `QGroupBox/QToolButton` in the tree means (looks like and/or but then sub-buttons don't make sense).

Comment: @MaxPaperno Re: `QGroupBox/QToolButton`: When the parent window shrinks enough  horizontally and the buttons collapsing doesn't provide enough space, the group box hides itself and and silently inserts a QToolButton in its place. Clicking on that tool button then displays the group box as a popup. Try resizing a Windows Explorer window to become very narrow and see how the group boxes collapse down to buttons.

Comment: Regarding dynamic objects: to clarify, a tool button collapsing due to available space may go from needing 33x90 pixels to 23x60. It's not a simple +/-. So the layout has to decide, "If I group these three (vertical) buttons" or "If I remove the text from these three (horizontal) buttons" the necessary space may change wildly. The bit that makes it all possible is that the "available space" is really just available horizontally--the toolbar (and thus its contents) is static vertically.

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic solution for this. You'll need to implement events/actions to take when the container is resized. It can be as simple or complex as you need. There are several different ways to go about actually implementing it, depending on complexity and scope involved (it is just a few items? the whole UI? etc...).

Here is a very basic (crude but effective) example which moves a toolbar to either be on the same line as another toolbar (for wider window) or to its own line (for narrower window). `MdiChild` in this case is a `QWidget` implementation which, obviously, contains other widgets and manages their layout.

```
void MdiChild::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)
{
  QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
  if (size().width() > ui->topToolbarLayout->sizeHint().width() + ui->botToolbarLayout->sizeHint().width() + 30) {
    ui->botToolbarLayout->removeWidget(modelsToolbar);
    ui->topToolbarLayout->insertWidget(1, modelsToolbar);
  }
  else {
    ui->topToolbarLayout->removeWidget(modelsToolbar);
    ui->botToolbarLayout->insertWidget(0, modelsToolbar);
  }
}
```

As you can see it has to take the container size into account, and the most direct way to do that is in the `QWidget::resizeEvent()`.  You could do anything here you want... change text buttons to icons, hide/show/move stuff... whatever.

Instead of handling the visual changes in the container, you could of course hook up signals/slots to the contained widgets... eg. a custom signal `emit availableSizeChanged(QSize size)` from the `resizeEvent()` handler `connect()`ed to the contained widget(s).

You may find [QStateMachine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html) handy to maintain visual state in a formal manner (this is what QML uses for it's `state[s]` property and transition system).

You could also implement your own `QLayout` as others have suggested. Though the scope of the question itself suggests you may not need to.  The question is quite general IMHO.  The two examples provided have massive differences in terms of complexity.

Comment: Thx, I tried the approach with "resizeEvent" - but there are exist one huge problem: when the main window have size that == pLayout->sizeHint() and I try to decrease window size via mouse - the "resizeEvent" is not call and the window size didnt change. But in your example the comparison proceed with tolerance (30) - this workaround helps very much.

Comment: could you please show how to implement above toolbar example with QLayout? I dont get how it could be.

Comment: @AeroSun On the first comment, you have to play with size policies/constraints and other layout options... sounds like there is a minimum size past which it will not shrink any more (and hence no resize event).

Comment: @AeroSun As for a custom QLayout, I'm not actually sure this makes sense here. To me it sounds like your layout will be pretty standard (eg. HBox), but it's the elements inside which need to change based on available size. So regardless of the layout used, I think you need to re-implement the element(s) which are going to change state (in the MS toolbar these elements are actually groups of widgets). Then you "just" need some way to notify these elements about available size. You may want/need to re-implement `QWidget::sizeHint()` in these custom elements.